# creating symlink

Tags: linux, filesystems, symlink

On my support machine, my `/` filesystem is very small and I frequently get alerts.

```
df -h /
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root  7.8G  6.6G  805M  90% /
```

How can I create symlink for `/` filesystem so that size of all logs, its  files or applications will be reflected to a different filesystem - as `/data` mount has lot of space.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you want to do is create a symlink from `/` to `/data`.

Which would be:

`ln -s / /data`

However that sounds like it will re-direct all items on your OS to `/data` rather than some of them.

Rather, it would probably be better to re-direct a certain logfile to this `/data` volume.  The example below will create a symbolic link (-s) from `/var/log/` to `/data/log`.

`ln -s /var/log/ /data/log/`

See [the manual page for ln](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) for more information.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. how ever even after adding softlinks, my disk utization is showing same.  may be i am doing something wrong .. here is the o/p                                   before softlink  => #-> df -h /
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root  7.8G  6.3G  1.2G  85% /

Creating soft link as mysqld logs are here ==>  #-> ln -s  /usr/sbin/ /data/sbin

(after soft link is created, checking again ) #-> df -h /
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root  7.8G  6.3G  1.2G  85% /

Comment: Did you try your suggestion (or one similar)? `ln -s / /data` will error out with, `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/data': File exists`